# c++ builder ZipProgress callback for the progress bar

Tags: callback, c++builder

I have a simple form, and I'm trying to work with the ProgressBar when a `.zip` file is being created, based on the **`ZipDirectoryContents` callback**. I have seen some Delphi example in the forum, but I don't know it well, and I get several errors. Here an example:

.cpp

```
#include <system.zip.hpp>

String PreviousFilename;
bool __fastcall createZipFromFolder( String inZipName,
                                     String inSourcePath,
                                     String inTargetPath )
{
      bool result = true;
      sZipName = "C:\\test\\testBar.zip";
      sSourceName = "C:\\test2";
      TZipFile* Zip = new TZipFile();
      try{
        if ( FileExists( sZipName ) ){
            Zip->ZipDirectoryContents( sZipName,                // destiny
                                       sSourceName,             // to include
                                       zcDeflate,               // compression mode
                                       OnZipProgressEvent() );  // <--- p callback
            Zip->Close();
        }
      }
      catch(...){
        result = false;
        ShowMessage("Error");
      }
      delete Zip;
      Zip = NULL;
      return result;
}

void __fastcall OnZipProgressEvent( TObject* Sender, String FileName, TZipHeader Header, __int64 Position )
{
  if ( PreviousFilename != FileName ){
    PreviousFilename = FileName;
    Form1->ProgressBar1->Max = Header.UncompressedSize;
    Form1->ProgressBar1->Position = Position;
  }
  else{
    Form1->ProgressBar1->Position = Position;
    Application->ProcessMessages();
  }
}
```

.h

```
#include <System.Zip.hpp>

public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TForm1(TComponent* Owner);

    typedef void __fastcall ( __closure * TZipProgressEvent )( TObject*,
                                                               String,
                                                               TZipHeader,
                                                               __int64 );
    bool __fastcall createZipFromFolder( String inZipName,
                                         String inSourcePath,
                                         String inTargetPath );
    void __fastcall OnZipProgressEvent( TObject* Sender,
                                        String FileName,
                                        TZipHeader Header,
                                        __int64 Position );
};
extern PACKAGE TForm1 *Form1;
extern String PreviousFilename;

#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `Zip->ZipDirectoryContents()`, you need to change `OnZipProgressEvent()` to `&OnZipProgressEvent` instead.  You are trying to *call* the callback (with missing parameters) when you should be *passing its address*.

Also, in your `.cpp` file, both `createZipFromFolder()` and `OnZipProgressEvent()` need to be defined as being members of your Form class.

Also, in `OnZipProgressEvent()`, the `TZipHeader` parameter needs to be passed by const reference rather than by value, per the [documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Zip.TZipProgressEvent).

Try this:

Unit1.h

```
...

class TForm1 : public TForm
{
    ...
private:        // User declarations
    String PreviousFilename;
    void __fastcall OnZipProgressEvent( TObject* Sender,
                                        String FileName,
                                        const TZipHeader &Header,
                                        __int64 Position );

public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TForm1(TComponent* Owner);
    
    bool __fastcall createZipFromFolder( String inZipName,
                                         String inSourcePath,
                                         String inTargetPath );
};

extern PACKAGE TForm1 *Form1;
    
#endif
```

Unit1.cpp

```
...
#include "Unit1.h"
#include <System.Zip.hpp>

bool __fastcall TForm1::createZipFromFolder( String inZipName,
                                             String inSourcePath,
                                             String inTargetPath )
{
    bool result = true;
    sZipName = _D("C:\\test\\testBar.zip");
    sSourceName = _D("C:\\test2");
    PreviousFilename = _D("");
    TZipFile* Zip = new TZipFile();
    try{
        if ( FileExists( sZipName ) ){
            Zip->ZipDirectoryContents( sZipName,                // destiny
                                        sSourceName,             // to include
                                        zcDeflate,              // compression mode
                                        &OnZipProgressEvent );  // <--- p callback
            Zip->Close();
        }
    }
    catch(...){
        result = false;
        ShowMessage(_D("Error"));
    }
    delete Zip;
    Zip = NULL;
    return result;
}

void __fastcall TForm1::OnZipProgressEvent( TObject* Sender,
                                            String FileName,
                                            const TZipHeader &Header,
                                            __int64 Position )
{
    if ( PreviousFilename != FileName ){
        PreviousFilename = FileName;
        ProgressBar1->Max = Header.UncompressedSize;
        ProgressBar1->Position = Position;
    }
    else{
        ProgressBar1->Position = Position;
        Application->ProcessMessages();
    }
}
```